# Difference between join with and join on

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I wondering about this line

```
->leftJoin(
    'AppBundle\Entity\UserGroups',
    'UserGroups',
    \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH,
    'User.group_id = UserGroups.id'
);
```

This works fine, the result is okay.

But when I replace `::WITH` with `::ON` this causes an error:

> Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_WITH, got 'ON'

**So what are difference between `::WITH` and `::ON` ?**

Answer (score 1):

Look here:

https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Lexer.php

`T_ON` is not even a valid constant inside Doctrine's `Lexer` class,  which is why you are seeing the error.

Comment: OP is talking about this code-documented option - https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/old-prototype-3.x/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Expr/Join.php